# Meaning of "@far int* @near IntegerPointer;"

Tags: c, memory, pointers, convention

I have the following definition.

```
far int* near IntegerPointer;
```

Does this mean, a pointer placed in 'near' memory pointing to a integer placed in far memory area.

Can anyone please clarify.

Comment: What kind of compiler has such strange "directives" ?

Comment: @Oliver N.: Apple's Objective-C implementation hasn't got `@far` and `@near`. No idea about others.

Comment: Sorry !!! I actually intend to specify far memory area using '@far' and near memory area using '@near'. I have corrected my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you got that right.

Read declarations *(from the inside out and)*  from right to left:

```
@far int* @near IntegerPointer;
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

**IntegerPointer is a**

```
@far int* @near IntegerPointer;
          ^^^^^
```

IntegerPointer is a **@near**

```
@far int* @near IntegerPointer;
        ^
```

IntegerPointer is a @near **pointer**

```
@far int* @near IntegerPointer;
     ^^^
```

IntegerPointer is a @near pointer **to int**

```
@far int* @near IntegerPointer;
^^^^
```

IntegerPointer is a @near pointer to int **@far**
or IntegerPointer is a @near pointer to @far int

What `@near` and `@far` means, though, I have almost no idea.

Comment: Different addressing methods, I think.

Comment: Windows C compilers used to have near and far pointers, being (IIRC) 16 and 32 bits respectively.  I don't know why the "@" either, since it isn't in the body of the question.

Answer (score -1):

`[psyhic power on]` Yes you are right. :) `[psyhic power off]`

Just simple

```
@far int* IntegerPointer;
```

would be just pointer to `far` memory, whereas

```
int* @near IntegerPointer;
```

looks like pointer placed in `near` memory.

Answer (score -1):

```
@near unsigned char var;
// Variable located anywhere in 64K address space Variable located anywhere in 64K address space
```

Source: 
http://www.cosmic-software.com/faq/faq16.php